# External HDD bad sectors for the first time, any reason to worry?

Tags: windows, external-hard-drive, filesystems, ntfs

Recently, Windows told me there may be a problem with some sectors of my drive. I chose to repair, and I would like to know if there's any reason to worry. It's the first time in 2 years that this happened, and some days before it happened I accidentally ejected another drive and pulled out this one without ejecting it safely. I would also like to know if there's any program that could tell me which files were deleted, so I can put them back on their place.

CrystalDiskInfo status shows it is in a "good" condition, although no %.

[image]

Also, If I move the content of this drive to a new one, will it pass the corrupted files? This is the result of the checkdisk filesystem check:

> ```
> Chkdsk was executed in read/write mode.  
>
> Checking file system on K:
> Volume label is Seagate Expansion Drive.
>
> CHKDSK is verifying files (stage 1 of 3)...
> The attribute of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x0 in file 0x2e
> has allocated length of 0x1f730000 instead of 0x1f7b0000.
> Deleted corrupt attribute list entry
> with type code 128 in file 46.
> Unable to locate attribute with instance tag 0x0 and segment
> reference 0x2000000000cce.  The expected attribute type is 0x80.
> Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, $J)
> from file record segment 3278.
> Unable to locate attribute with instance tag 0x0 and segment
> reference 0x10000000173ae.  The expected attribute type is 0x80.
> Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, $J)
> from file record segment 95150.
> Unable to locate attribute with instance tag 0x0 and segment
> reference 0x1000000022422.  The expected attribute type is 0x80.
> Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, $J)
> from file record segment 140322.
> Unable to locate attribute with instance tag 0x0 and segment
> reference 0x2000000028b48.  The expected attribute type is 0x80.
> Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, $J)
> from file record segment 166728.
> Unable to locate attribute with instance tag 0x0 and segment
> reference 0x100000006a283.  The expected attribute type is 0x80.
> Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, $J)
> from file record segment 434819.
> Unable to locate attribute with instance tag 0x0 and segment
> reference 0x10000000706c5.  The expected attribute type is 0x80.
> Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, $J)
> from file record segment 460485.
> Unable to locate attribute with instance tag 0x0 and segment
> reference 0x100000008f95d.  The expected attribute type is 0x80.
> Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, $J)
> from file record segment 588125.
> Unable to locate attribute with instance tag 0x0 and segment
> reference 0x10000000aeda7.  The expected attribute type is 0x80.
> Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, $J)
> from file record segment 716199.
> 861184 file records processed.                                                              
> File verification completed.
> 2 large file records processed.                                                     
> 0 bad file records processed.                                      
> CHKDSK is verifying indexes (stage 2 of 3)...
> 922388 index entries processed.                                         
> Index verification completed.
>
>
> CHKDSK is verifying security descriptors (stage 3 of 3)...
> Deleting an index entry with Id 310 from index $SDH of file 9.
> Deleting an index entry with Id 311 from index $SDH of file 9.
> Cleaning up 21 unused index entries from index $SII of file 9.
> Cleaning up 21 unused index entries from index $SDH of file 9.
> Cleaning up 21 unused security descriptors.
> Security descriptor verification completed.
> 30603 data files processed.                                            
> CHKDSK is verifying Usn Journal...
> Creating Usn Journal $J data stream
> Usn Journal verification completed.
> CHKDSK discovered free space marked as allocated in the
> master file table (MFT) bitmap.
> CHKDSK discovered free space marked as allocated in the volume bitmap.
>
> Windows has made corrections to the file system.
> No further action is required.
>
> 1953511423 KB total disk space.
> 1741088100 KB in 829297 files.
> 386304 KB in 30604 indexes.
> 986863 KB in use by the system.
> 65536 KB occupied by the log file.
> 211050156 KB available on disk.
>
> 4096 bytes in each allocation unit.
> 488377855 total allocation units on disk.
> 52762539 allocation units available on disk.
> ```

Comment: Check your hard drives for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive's SMART status in Windows 7?](//superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](//superuser.com/q/14803). Report back with the results.

Comment: Where does it show that the disk has bad sectors? In the log I only see filesystem corruption.

Comment: Maybe I should expand on that. 'Bad sector' is like 'in the book this page is falling appart. There is a physical issue. filesystem corruption is like 'some words are smugged or misspelled. There is no dammage. You can erase and rewrite and all will be fine. And depending on the issue no data may be lost at all.

Comment: @DavidPostill I have CrystalDiskInfo, which I think does the same. It says the Drive's Health Status is good. Do you want me to upload an Image of the details it shows?. Thanks!

Comment: @Hennes That's nice, and is there a way to figure out if I've lost any data at all? Because I have the files backed up on another drive, but the info is too cryptic for me. Thanks!

Comment: @Interested Details are always good.

Comment: @DavidPostill Here are the details: http://imgur.com/a/nb7u6 Thanks for the help

Comment: @Interested Nothing wrong with that disk :)

Comment: @DavidPostill Then I only have to figure out which files it deleted, thanks a lot!